# Microsoft word vba macro insert a file with a link to a file

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am not a good programmer, so all help is welcome.

I want to create a simple script. When I insert an image I want to automatically add the option Link to File.

I created a script, but the problem is that I need to select the file two times before Word inserts it (it actually only adds one file).
Any idea what I am doing wrong?

```
Sub InsertLinkToFile()
'
' InsertLinkToFile Macro
'
'
    Dim strPicName As String
    Dim vShape As InlineShape

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker) 'Dialogs(wdDialogInsertPicture)
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .Title = "Select the File that you want to insert"
    .Show
    .Filters.Add "Images", "*.gif; *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png", 1
    FiletoInsert = .SelectedItems(1)

        If .Show = -1 Then
            strPicName = .SelectedItems(1)
            With ActiveDocument

                Set vShape = .InlineShapes.AddPicture(FileName:=strPicName, LinkToFile:=True, SaveWithDocument:=False)

            End With
        End If
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: You have two lines with a `.Show` - just drop the first one.

Answer (score 0):

The modified script:

```
    Sub InsertLinkToFile()
    '
    ' InsertLinkToFile Macro
    '
    '
        Dim strPicName As String
        Dim vShape As InlineShape

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker) 'Dialogs(wdDialogInsertPicture)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Select the File that you want to insert"
      '  .Show  ' remove this line
        .Filters.Add "Images", "*.gif; *.jpg; *.jpeg; *.png", 1

     If .Show = True Then
       FiletoInsert = .SelectedItems(1)
       strPicName = .SelectedItems(1)
       Set vShape = ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.AddPicture(strPicName, True, False)            
     End If
   End With
End Sub
```